# Sum of powers of 2 from 1 to log(N).

Tags: power-series

I came across the following sum: $\sum_{m=1}^{\log_2(N)} 2^{m}$. My intuition tells me that this should be bounded by 2N, but how would I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^d x^n= \frac{x^{d+1}-1}{x-1}$$

So we have:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\log_2 N} 2^m=\sum_{m=0}^{\log_2 N} 2^m-2^0=\sum_{m=0}^{ \log_2 N } 2^m-1 =  \frac{2^{\lfloor \log_2N \rfloor +1}-1}{2-1}-1 \leq  \frac{N \cdot 2-1}{1}-1 \\=N \cdot 2-2 $$

Comment: This works exactly for a power of two. If $N$ is not a power of two the argument almost works but you have to interpret the log as a floor of the log base 2.

Comment: It always holds that $2^{\log_2{x}}=x$, it doesn't depend on $x$. @amcalde

Comment: Sure, but what does it mean to have $\sum_{i=1}^{5.5}$?

Comment: What you say is true. But I don't know how to do a discrete sum over an integer ($m$) when the upper limit is not an integer. Hence my comment.

Comment: Ah, I see... @amcalde

Comment: If you wrap the final log in a floor function, then use a less than or equal to sign instead of the next equal sign. The argument is exactly right.

Comment: @amcalde I edited my post. Do you agree with it now?

Comment: Yes. I already up voted.

Comment: @amcalde Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For any $p \in \mathbb{N}$ you have:
$$\sum_{m=1}^p 2^m = 2^{p+1}-2=2\cdot2^p - 2$$

So:
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\log_2(N)} 2^m = 2N-2$$ Which is indeed bounded by $2N$